# What is the correct way to validate Circular Associations in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Given:

```
def Node
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: :Node
  has_many :children, class_name: :Node, foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

I am trying to create a Validation to make sure that a Node cannot be it's own parent, or it's parent's parent, etc.

I got this:

```
# Custom validator to check if the Parent Node is related to the current node. Avoids that ugly self-association loop.
#
class NodeParentValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(node)
    @node = node

    unless validate_recursive(node)
      node.errors[:parent_id] << "Node can't be it's own parent"
    end

  end

  def validate_recursive(node)
    # If the validating node doesn't have a parent, we return true because we're either facing a node that doesn't have any parent
    # or we got to the point that we need to stop the recursive loop.
    return true if node.parent.nil?
    # If the validating node is the same as the current "parent", we found the self-association loop. This is bad.
    return false if @node.id == node.parent_id
    # While we don't get to the end of the association, keep jumping.
    return false unless validate_recursive(node.parent)
    return true
  end

end
```

And it totally works! That is the problem actually. Is it works. When Rails called the assign_attributes method, I get a 422, but it doesn't have my Validation in it! Instead I get an ugly HTML validation error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace children because one or more of the new records could not be saved.)
```

So if Rails can't save it's associated records Rails returns it's own Error (the one in a code block above), but if my Record is associated to itself, I get a large problem. Even if I stop the Node from validating it's associated children/parents, I still get an error.

As long as the record I am trying to save ITSELF has an error, then Rails replaces my 422 with the error above. And that is just plain bad. I want a JSON response error so my client knows what exactly went wrong.

I find it hard to believe that no one else has run into this problem, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm finding it a little difficult to follow what you're saying in the last 3 paragraphs because you use the pronoun "it" to refer to so many different things. The logic of the custom validator looks fine to me based on what you said you wanted it to do. If your record is associated to itself, why is it a problem that you get an error? You said that's supposed to happen, right? Or is your issue simply that you want your validator's error message to show up in your log instead of the one you are actually getting?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was getting pretty late at night and I guess I start hating Pronoun's at that point. Hopefully the question makes more sense now.

The problem is with what the error is, I want the error I get from my Validation, not Rails' Generic ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved error. It is one thing to prevent the association from being persisted, but it is a whole other thing to get record to return my own error: "Node can't be it's own parent".

Comment: Oh, so couldn't you put a conditional in your controller that if the creation fails, it calls the errors method on the model and returns that with the JSON response? In this way you are explicitly telling Rails what you want the JSON response message to be? Anyway, perhaps Rails is getting confused because you technically are still trying to create a child association if the record is referencing itself, and it's through validating this child association that it fails, hence the message which has to be vague since it's  a has_many association and must make sense even with multiple errors.

Comment: Doesn't quite work that way unfortunately, the 422 is returned from within Rails::Persistence's .update method, so there is no handling it without catching the error, and ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved is a pretty dangerous one to catch. Moreover, it would violate MVC. Our Model's should be responsible for catching this, via Validations. Putting code in the controller to stop this from happening would be easy, but it would cause confusion down the line.

Comment: As for the child association, I checked this out. I disabled the Node validating it's associated children and parent. The only Node with errors is the one I am trying to update. That being said, the Node is technically it's own child (and it's own parent) at this point, so your assumption is at least half-right!

Comment: I'm not saying to catch the error, I'm saying to conditionally watch the creation to see if it fails or not and handle a failure accordingly, which is standard practice in Rails controllers. You wouldn't want to put how to handle a JSON response in case of failure inside of your model, that goes in a controller. This is essentially a workaround to make sure your JSON users get a good message despite the weird Rails behavior. But yeah, the fact that you disabled the Node from validating its associations yet still gives an error as though it did is pretty strange indeed. I'm stumped on that one.

Comment: Right but the error happens inside the .update method, and no further code is executed. So there is not point in putting code after the update. Either I have to monkey patch .update, catch the error from the outside, or check before the update (and all of these options are horrible)

Comment: If anyone else is looking at this wondering where the next step is, maybe you can strike some sense into these guys, they seem to not agree that this is an issue with Rails rather than my own code.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21319

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the validator in the `Node` model? If so the above code should work.

I tried this,

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :children, class_name: :Node, foreign_key: :parent_id
   belongs_to :parent, class_name: :Node, foreign_key: :parent_id

   validates_with NodeParentValidator
end
```

The validator code is same. Here is the result of testing in console.

[image: Here is the result of the testing in console]

Comment: Yes, I had the Validator added to the model, still didn't work. Also, are you sure your example is working? You have the foreign key on both associations... this feels wrong, no?

To me this says a Node has a parent, that is identified by that parent Node's parent_id. This makes no sense!

Comment: Yes, you are right, you would use the `parent_id` to fetch the parent of a `Node`. The relationship in the database is maintained using the `foreign_key` `parent_id`. I was explicit to make it readable

Rails by default uses the 'resource name' +  '_id' i.e parent_id to fetch the parent. But in case of `has_many` relationship it will look for `node_id` column. So we would need to specify the `foreign_key` as `parent_id`. 

For more info you can have a look at `self join` and `Creating Foreign Keys for belongs_to Associations` section in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Right, I understand foreign keys, but check out the documentation you linked, you're example is without a doubt wrong. You don't want to foreign key on BOTH relationships. Think of it this way, for a Node's children relationship, you place an id on each of the children that points to the parent; you DO NOT want to place an id on your parent, that points to the children, which is what you have done above. I think this may have something to do with you getting your 422 with errors, but do you see why this is bad?

Comment: `belongs_to` relationship always uses the `foreign_key`. For more info.  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to 

The `foreign_key` is always kept in a child table. In this case as its a single table you keep it in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add errors to the initial node:

```
def validate(node)
    @node = node

    unless validate_recursive(node)
      @node.errors[:parent_id] << "Node can't be it's own parent"
    end
end
```